# configuring git/ssh to access bitbucket results in keyfile rejected - format error?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, bitbucket, putty

I have been trying for 3 days now to set up git/ssh to work with bitbucket.org on windows 10. 
Made a little progress. Now the log is...

```
   Ian@Helike MINGW64 /m/websites/coachmaster (master)
$ ssh -v git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Ian Hobson/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Ian Hobson/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file D:\\Ian\\keyfiles\\ianhobson-bitbucket type -1
debug1: identity file D:\\Ian\\keyfiles\\ianhobson-bitbucket-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_e350bda95a app-131
debug1: no match: conker_e350bda95a app-131
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Ian Hobson/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: D:\\Ian\\keyfiles\\ianhobson-bitbucket  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: D:\\Ian\\keyfiles\\ianhobson-bitbucket
sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).

Ian@Helike MINGW64 /m/websites/coachmaster (master)
```

I can see it is using the correct keyfile. That keyfile, and ~/.ssh/config have been copied from the old machine where it works.

Ian

Comment: OpenSSH does not support .ppk keys. You have to use PuTTYgen to convert the .ppk to OpenSSH format. Btw, this is not really a programming question.

Comment: Tried copying the ~/.ssh/config and D:/whateer/keyfiles from the old machine where it works.   Got same failure on the new machine.

Comment: You do not get the same failure at all. Now the problem is very different.

Answer (score 1):

Try and regenerate your keys with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.com" -m PEM -P "" -f D:\Ian\keyfiles\ianhobson-bitbucket
```

Then add the public key to your BitBucket profile.

Make sure your ~/.ssh/config file references that private key

```
Host bitb
Hostname bitbucket.org
User git
IdentityFile D:\Ian\keyfiles\ianhobson-bitbucket
```

Then your URL should be:

```
ssh -v bitb
```

(*not* `git@bitbicket.org`, which would bypass the SSH config file entirely)

> I think my error was to install git/tortoise git attempting to use Putty and plink - maybe I tried a mix.

I confirm (as I did [in the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201376/discussion-between-ian-and-vonc)): no Putty should be needed. OpenSSH is enough.

Comment: I tried it, not expecting it to work - the old key works from another machine. However I did get logged in so a small step forward.  Thanks for that. However "git pull" still fails with "FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)". Not there yet.

Comment: @Ian What is your `git remote -v remote` URL used by `git  pull`? And what is the exact content of  your `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: Config file is: \nHost bitbucket.org\n
    Hostname bitbucket.org\n
    IdentityFile D:\Ian\keyfiles\ianhobson-bitbucket2

Comment: Remote URL is: url = git@bitbucket.org:IanHobson/<repo>.git

Comment: @Ian OK, you can add the User, and only use bitbucket.org. I would use a different name for the host, just to be usre to be using the config settings.

Comment: @Ian Next stop is to check if you have properly registered your public SSH key `D:\Ian\keyfiles\ianhobson-bitbucket2.pub`, in one line (and not three separate line during the copy paste)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201376/discussion-between-ian-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
I think my error was to install git/tortoise git attempting to use Putty and plink - maybe I tried a mix.

I should have used the other option - Open-SSH? - for both programs.

I went about recovery the long way, by resetting windows and re-installing all programs, so I can not be 100% sure that removing and reinstalling git and tortoise git in this way would have solved the problem.

And a special thanks to VonC for all his efforts to help.